# Can I schedule a build for onetime run in Jenkins ? Any solution without cron

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I don't need cron job because the build is needed to run only once in production and not periodically.Is there a way to build the pipeline at a scheduled time without cron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do is - You can trigger it remotely
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/

Let's say you got a Linux box, you can schedule it by using the "at" command

```
at 9:30 PM Fri

curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build \
  --data token=TOKEN \
  --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"id", "value":"123"},\
     {"name":"verbosity", "value":"high"}]}'
job 2 at Fri Jan 29 21:30:00 2016
```

Then look at it with

```
at -c 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule a build using Groovy via script console or job using: [`scheduleBuild2`](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractProject.html#scheduleBuild2-int-hudson.model.Cause-):

```java
def waittime = 100   // in secs
def jobName = 'folder/jobname'   //aka it.fullName

Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName).scheduleBuild2(waittime)
```

**quietPeriod - seconds to wait before starting (normally 0)**

> `public QueueTaskFuture<R> scheduleBuild2(int quietPeriod, Action... actions)`
>
> Description copied from interface:
> ParameterizedJobMixIn.ParameterizedJob Provides a standard
> implementation of SCMTriggerItem.scheduleBuild2(int,
> hudson.model.Action...) to schedule a build with the ability to wait
> for its result. That job method is often used during functional tests
> (JenkinsRule.assertBuildStatusSuccess).
>
> Specified by:     scheduleBuild2 in interface
> ParameterizedJobMixIn.ParameterizedJob<P extends
> AbstractProject<P,R>,R extends AbstractBuild<P,R>> Parameters:
> quietPeriod - seconds to wait before starting (normally 0)  actions -
> various actions to associate with the scheduling, such as
> ParametersAction or CauseAction Returns:  a handle by which you may
> wait for the build to complete (or just start); or null if the build
> was not actually scheduled for some reason

Comment: Hi, I tried this approach and it works. However when someone executes the job manually, the one we placed via scheduleBuild2 that is waiting gets overridden, like Jenkins thinks we intended to run the pending job immediately, not a separate execution. Do you know any workaround for this?

Comment: I think that's rather expected behavior. If say a node is down, and multiple triggers for what will be "the same build", one build satisfies them all. One option was [Random String Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/random-string-parameter), but has vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a similar approach, where I assigned a guid to each scheduled build to make them unique.