# Trigger a job once in the future

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to manually build a job with a delayed start?
I.e. Can I easily do "build this job in 8 hours"?

I can set a weird schedule to run it like once a year, but it really seems like a hack.

Comment: I [answered this before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63405325/598141), tho it was after the "accepted" answer.

Comment: I have a requirement that is probably similar to yours. Job AAA gets run (at an ad-hoc time by req) and I want Job BBB to run about 30 minutes after that. But using the sleep period, or using a delay task - either keep an executor occupied. Scheduler Plugin might accommodate this case. I think that Ian W's link shows the best approach. Question: Will that keep an executor occupied?

Answer (score 0):

Just install the plugin scheduler plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/schedule-build/

Comment: I'm trying to avoid Jenkins plugins as they get out-dated, abandoned or deprecated too often.