# Cron expression for trigger job for next 3 days after initial trigger

Tags: jenkins, cron

- I want a Jenkins job to run for 3 days at interval of 24 hrs. after initial trigger of Job.
  Say if i trigger the job now . It should run at (now + 24) then at (now + 48) and later (now + 72).
- I could find a expression : '0 */24 * * */3' , This runs At 0 minutes past the hour, every 24 hours, every 3 days of the week .
  Need some help to modify as per initial requirement.

Comment: That's not [how cron works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12472645/598141)

Comment: @IanW  : Is their a way to achieve this requirement ? Any leads are welcome.

Comment: [Can I schedule a build for onetime run in Jenkins ? Any solution without cron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63405325/598141). Do it 3x.