# Schedule job at specific dates

Tags: jenkins, cron, scheduler

How to :

Schedule job at specific dates across several months ?

it will be ~10 dates.

Second is there a tool that simulate cron, such that u can pass date/time and the tool tell you did cron triggers or not

Comment: Check out [This Simulator](https://crontab.cronhub.io/) and [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472645/how-do-i-schedule-jobs-in-jenkins)

Answer (score 1):

[cron](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) does not schedule events in that manner. Jenkins scheduler is cron-based.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63400930/598141) provides several options.

Apparently there is now a released plugin - [Schedule Build](https://plugins.jenkins.io/schedule-build/) which appears to support calling the **scheduleBuild** action referenced in my [groovy based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63405325/598141).

See [constraint](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-59612) (you can only schedule one build at a time) [unless parameterized](https://plugins.jenkins.io/random-string-parameter/).